# How do I add a generated unique link into an email which will lead to an encrypted page?

Tags: email, encryption, hyperlink, html

Allow me to better explain: the company I work for work alongside holiday camps etc and want to add a link into the booking confirmation email which will take them through to a web page (which can only be accessed through the unique link) to sign up to our service.

What we need is to be able to have an automatically generated link within the email which can then be used to access the page and stop any random person signing up that happens to have a link.

Any info or suggestions would be welcome, even a jumping off point to research further would be fantastic- cheers!

Comment: I don't see the need for encryption. Use a unique token like a UUID. The token is stored in your DB and sent to the user.

Comment: Hey Artjom, So this link would only work per person? We want to avoid it being sharable of course.

Comment: Any link can be shared. There is no such thing as an encrypted page, because at some point somebody needs to look at it.